# Inverting an image using MPI

Tags: image, matrix, mpi

I am trying to invert a PGM image using MPI. The grayscale (PGM) image should be loaded on the root processor and then be sent to each of the s^2 processors. Each processor will invert a block of the given image, and the inverted blocks will be gathered back on the root processor, which will assemble the blocks into the final image and write it to a PGM image. I ran the following code, but did not get any output. The image was read after running the code, but there was no indication of writing the resultant image. Could you please let me know what could be wrong with it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <memory.h>


#define max(x, y) ((x>y) ? (x):(y))
#define min(x, y) ((x<y) ? (x):(y))


int xdim;
int ydim;
int maxraw;
unsigned char *image;




void ReadPGM(FILE*);
void WritePGM(FILE*);


#define s 2

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    int p, rank;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);



    const int NPROWS=s;  /* number of rows in _decomposition_ */
    const int NPCOLS=s;  /* number of cols in _decomposition_ */

    const int BLOCKROWS = xdim/NPROWS;  /* number of rows in _block_ */
    const int BLOCKCOLS = ydim/NPCOLS; /* number of cols in _block_ */

    int i, j;
    FILE *fp;




    float BLimage[BLOCKROWS*BLOCKCOLS];
    for (int ii=0; ii<BLOCKROWS*BLOCKCOLS; ii++)
        BLimage[ii] = 0;


    float  BLfilteredMat[BLOCKROWS*BLOCKCOLS];
    for (int ii=0; ii<BLOCKROWS*BLOCKCOLS; ii++)
        BLfilteredMat[ii] = 0;


    if (rank == 0) {


        /* begin reading PGM.... */


        ReadPGM(fp);
    }


    MPI_Datatype blocktype;
    MPI_Datatype blocktype2;

    MPI_Type_vector(BLOCKROWS, BLOCKCOLS, ydim, MPI_FLOAT, &blocktype2);


    MPI_Type_create_resized( blocktype2, 0, sizeof(float), &blocktype);
    MPI_Type_commit(&blocktype);

    int disps[NPROWS*NPCOLS];
    int counts[NPROWS*NPCOLS];



    for (int ii=0; ii<NPROWS; ii++) {
        for (int jj=0; jj<NPCOLS; jj++) {
            disps[ii*NPCOLS+jj] = ii*ydim*BLOCKROWS+jj*BLOCKCOLS;
            counts [ii*NPCOLS+jj] = 1;
        }
    }

    MPI_Scatterv(image, counts, disps, blocktype, BLimage, BLOCKROWS*BLOCKCOLS, MPI_FLOAT, 0,     MPI_COMM_WORLD);



    //************** Invert the block **************//


    for (int proc=0; proc<p; proc++) {

        if (proc == rank) {

            for (int j = 0; j < BLOCKCOLS; j++) {
                for (int i = 0; i < BLOCKROWS; i++) {

                    BLfilteredMat[j*BLOCKROWS+i] = 255 - image[j*BLOCKROWS+i];

                }
            }
        }  // close  if (proc == rank) {


        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    }   //  close for (int proc=0; proc<p; proc++) {



    MPI_Gatherv(BLfilteredMat, BLOCKROWS*BLOCKCOLS,MPI_FLOAT, image, counts, disps,blocktype, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);


    if (rank == 0) {

        /* Begin writing PGM.... */

        WritePGM(fp);

        free(image);

    }  

    MPI_Finalize();

    return (1);

}
```

Comment: I am kind of new to this website and I would like to know why this this question has been down voted?

Comment: as to why your question was downvoted: The reason is likely that it does not conform with the posting guidelines: If possible at all, post a [minimal, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Maybe you should have restricted yourself to only outlining the MPI calls.

Comment: why did you choose the architecture you have in mind (master + s**2 worker nodes)?

Comment: Thanks. I edited the code by only focusing on the MPI part and removed the functions code.

Comment: The architecture I used here is what is defined in the project I am supposed to do for my parallel programing course.The image must be loaded on a root processor, be sent to other (s*s) processors in the form of blocks, apply the filter to the blocks, and then gather the filtered blocks on the root processor to be written to an image. The value of s is supposed to change for 3 cases: s=1, s=2, s=4.

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely MPI is not the right tool for the job. The reason for this is that your job is inherently bandwidth limited.

Think of it this way: You have a coloring book with images which you all want to color in.

- **Method 1**: you take your time and color them in one by one.
- **Method 2**: you copy each page to a new sheet of paper and mail it to a friend who then colors it in for you. He mails it back to you and in the end you glue all the pages you received from all of your friends together to make one colored-in book.

Note that method two involves copying the whole book, which is arguably the same amount of work needed to color in the whole book. So method two is less time-efficient without even considering the overhead of shoving the pages into an envelope, licking the stamp, going to the post office and waiting for the letter to be delivered.

If you look at your code, every transmitted byte is only touched once throughout the whole program in this line:

```
BLfilteredMat[j*BLOCKROWS+i] = 255 - image[j*BLOCKROWS+i];
```

The single processor is much faster at subtracting two integers than it is at sending an integer of the wire, therefore one must advise against using MPI for your particular problem.

**My suggestion to solve your problem:** Try to avoid unneccessary communication whenever possible. Do all processes have access to the file system on which the files are located? You could try reading them directly from the filesystem.

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed explanation. As a matter of fact, my ultimate purpose by doing this job with MPI is applying a bilateral filter at the end. But before going for that part, I just wanted to make sure that my MPI code works fine, so I decided to test it with a single line code to invert the image. Once I make sure about the MPI part, I only need to change the filter code.